# Why these two sets have to be disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Consider the following relation between sets in $3$-dimensional Euclidean space. We say
$$X\approx Y$$ if there is a finite decomposition of $X$ into disjoint sets $X=X_1\cup X_2\cup\cdots\cup X_m$ and a decomposition of $Y$ into same number of disjoint sets $Y=Y_1\cup Y_2\cup\cdots\cup Y_m$
such that $X_i$ is congruent to $Y_i$ for each $i=1,2,\cdots,m$.

Now I was studying the proof of the following statement:

> If $X_1\subseteq Y\subseteq X$ and if $X_1\approx X$, then $X\approx Y$.

Proof that I read: Let $X=X^1\cup\cdots\cup X^n$ and $X_1=X^1_1\cup\cdots\cup X^n_1$ such that $X^i$ congruent to $X_1^i$, $i=1,\cdots,n.$ Choose a congruence $f^i:X^i\to X_1^i$, $i=1,\cdots,n$. Let $f$ be a one-to one mapping of $X$ onto $X_1$ which agrees with $f^i$ on each $X^i$. Now let
$$X_0=X,\ X_1=\mathrm{Im}_f(X_0),\ X_2=\mathrm{Im}_f(X_1),\cdots$$
$$Y_0=Y,\ Y_1=\mathrm{Im}_f(Y_0),\ Y_2=\mathrm{Im}_f(Y_1),\cdots$$
(where $\mathrm{Im}_f(A)=\{f(a)\mid a\in A\}$, the image of $A$ under $f$). Let $$Z=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}(X_n\setminus Y_n)$$
then $\mathrm{Im}_f(Z)$ and $X\setminus Z$ are disjoint, and $\mathrm{Im}_f(Z)\approx Z$. As we can write $$X=Z\cup(X\setminus Z),\ \ \ Y=\mathrm{Im}_f(Z)\cup(X\setminus Z)$$
hence we have $X\approx Y$.

**Now I have difficulty in understanding only one of the above claims:**

> $\mathrm{Im}_f(Z)$ and $X\setminus Z$ are disjoint.

Can anyone elaborate why that should be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in Z$; then $x\in X_n\setminus Y_n$ for some $n\ge 0$, and $f(x)\in f[X_n\setminus Y_n]$. Clearly $f[X_n\setminus Y_n]\subseteq f[X_n]=X_{n+1}$. Moreover, $f$ is injective, $x\notin Y_n$, and $Y_{n+1}=f[Y_n]$, so $f(x)\notin Y_{n+1}$, and therefore $f(x)\in X_{n+1}\setminus Y_{n+1}\subseteq Z$. Thus, $f[Z]\subseteq Z$, and hence $f[Z]$ and $X\setminus Z$ are disjoint.